# Request Payload Changed from JSON to other format on ajax call over HTTPS

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, https, ssl-certificate

I have created one self SSL-Certificate of format i,e demo.ssl.cer.p7b.
Added this certificate in JDK and web browser under trusted certificate storage.

When the application was working on HTTP,  I used to receive the request payload in JSON format which was correct.

Now after enabling HTTPS on server side,the request payload format has been changed and it is not in JSON.

Not able to understand the data and also not sure how the message is changed and delivered to the controller. Can anyone please suggest more information on understanding the same.

Note : Posting through AJAX.

Request payload

```
{
          "producerAPI": {
            "host": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx",
            "port": "84xx",
            "context": "iProducer/getDataDB"
          },
          "consumerAPI": {
            "host": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx",
            "port": "84xx",
            "context": "ConsumerAPI/consumerAPIXml"
          },
         "dataMapper":{
                        "inputFormat":"json",
                        "outputFormat":"xml"
            }

        }
```

Once request reaches controller, we are getting below mentioned format

```
producerAPI%5Bhost%5D=localhost&producerAPI%5Bport%5D=84XX&producerAPI%5Bcontext%5D=iPaaSProducer%2FgetDataFromDB&consumerAPI%5Bhost%5D=xx.xx.xxx.xxx&consumerAPI%5Bport%5D=80XX&consumerAPI%5Bcontext%5D=ConsumerAPI%2FconsumerAPIXml&dataMapper%5BinputFormat%5D=json&dataMapper%5BoutputFormat%5D=xml
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue got resolved by stringifying request payload.